# Flyway repair throws FlywaySqlException with Oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle, spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

I am trying to use flyway repair method to delete unsuccessful migration entries from schema versioning table with spring boot configuration. My code is like this;

```
@Bean
public FlywayMigrationStrategy repairStrategy() {
    return flyway -> {
        flyway.repair();
        flyway.migrate();
    };
}
```

But after run, it throws an error like this(repair operation fails even when migration operation is commented out);

```
Error while retrieving the list of applied migrations from Schema History table 
SQL State  : 72000 
Error Code : 12838 
Message    : ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel
```

Do you have any ideas? Is there any parallel operation here? Btw, I am using Oracle ATP database and flyway community edition.

Comment: Does the migration run in a transaction?

Comment: no, flyway should care about transaction.

Comment: Oracle DDL is not transactional (unlike Postgres) so FlyWay will never be able to rollback a data model change (here the Repair feature comes in handy)

I wonder if Spring Transaction management creates a problem here, I would try to separate the repair() and migrate() in different methods (maybe even beans)

Comment: but repair operation fails even when migration operation is commented out, exception comes from inside of repair.

Answer (score 0):

Flyway repair will not repair your database for you ([see docs here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/repair)). What it does is repair the schema history table back to a valid state. Fixing the database is left up to the user (as it is a non-trivial task).

In this situation, you can try submitting a `commit;`. This should allow you to run repair and then migrate again.
See: https://dbaclass.com/article/ora-12838-cannot-readmodify-object-modifying-parallel/