# How to make Oracle ALTER TABLE MODIFY script be idempotent?

Tags: oracle, database-migration, ddl, idempotent

I have this migration script;

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY (column_name NULL);
```

How do I make it idempotent?

Comment: Use tools like Liquibase or Flyway

Comment: since I have this kind of problems (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59666601/flyway-repair-throws-flywaysqlexception-with-oracle-db) I dont prefer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either you can use an exception handler:

```
DECLARE
    CANNOT_MODIFIY_TO_NULL EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(CANNOT_MODIFIY_TO_NULL, -1451);
BEGIN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME MODIFY (column_name  NULL)';
exception
    when CANNOT_MODIFIY_TO_NULL then
        NULL;
END;
```

or check `NULLABLE` in view `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`:

```
DECLARE

    CURSOR Cols IS
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME' 
        AND NULLABLE = 'N' 
        AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COLUMN_NAME';

BEGIN
    FOR aCol IN Cols LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME MODIFY ('||aCol.COLUMN_NAME||' NULL)';
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that if it's a migration script being run in SQL*Plus, you could also use `WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE` before the command as a rudimentary exception handler.

Comment: @kfinity yes, however then it ignores any error including those you may want to see. That's the reason why I did not use `exception when OTHERS then null;`